# PHP if condition with or not working

Tags: php

I have this condition here:

```
if($name != '' || $name != 0 || $name != "0"){
       $where .= ' AND readyBuilt.home_title = "' . $name . '"';
}
```

My problem with this condition if `$name` is equal to "0" it still adds the `$where` to my `$where` variable. how do I fix this ?

Comment: `!=` only compares value not the data type you can use `!==` or use `!empty($name)` instead of comparing it with '' and 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 if ( !in_array($name, array('','0',0), true ) ) {
   $where .= ' AND readyBuilt.home_title = "' . $name . '"';
 }
```

Comment: works, however the other solutions are much more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

i think, you mean something else, try use `&&` instead of `||`

Answer (score 3):

Well, if this statement is true:

> $name is equal to "0"

Then this condition evaluates to `true`:

```
$name != ''
```

Therefore the entire conditional check evaluates to `true`.

It sounds like you want to use `&&` instead of `||`:

```
if($name != '' && $name != 0 && $name != "0")
```

That way the entire condition will evaluate to `true` only if all three conditions are met, instead of only one condition.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to use :

```
if(!empty($name))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just using this should solve your issue:

```
if($name){
 //your condition
}
```